# how to continuously watch for scope variable until update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular.js there is $watch to watch the scoped variables for updates. but is there anything that I can do, such as execute a function until the variable gets updated

Comment: Why you can't use angular `$watch` and just to check the updated value and if the value matches your desire to do something with it?

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to listen to that element until changes. not after the change

Comment: @SibiRaj 1. wrap your handler as the return from an IIFE. 2. Set a flag `var seen = false;` in your handler, `if (seen) return; seen = true;`

Comment: will try that @PaulS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   //try this (please inject $interval service to your controller)
    var execueMe = function () {
        //your stuff
    }

    $interval(execueMe, 3000); //will trigger every 3 seconds
```

Comment: so I can just use $interval.

Comment: not a great approach as it will observe the value but the check will never stop even if the variable gets updated moreover it will have negative impact over performance.

Comment: yes but he added in comment that he wants to execute fn whether is update or not..so what could be the another approach ?

Comment: You can cancel the $interval timer once the value stabilizes.

Answer (score 3):

watch until value change

```
var watchVar = $scope.$watch('value', function(newValue , oldValue){
  if(newValue!=oldValue){
  //value changed remove watch
  watchVar();
 }
});
```

Comment: it won't work I think. because the watchVar is called only when the `newValue` and `oldValue` are not equal. It will terminate on first time initialization

Comment: @SibiRaj did not get what you wanted , but here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/954eve2L/1729/) it works

Comment: yeah, it works but my requirement is different. also your answer clarified another one of my doubts

Comment: I accepted the answer provided bt NanishModi. I satisfies almost what I am looking for